# CakePHP: loads plugin for test

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a plugin (`FirstPlugin`).
The plugin loads a second plugin (`SecondPlugin`) from its bootstrap and they work both fine.

Now I'm writing tests for `FirstPlugin` and I need to load `SecondPlugin` into tests.

So in the bootstrap for test (`FirstPlugin/tests/bootstrap.php`) I just require the main bootstrap (`FirstPlugin/config/bootstrap.php`):

```
require ROOT . 'config' . DS . 'bootstrap.php';
```

I do this because I also need other bootstrap code (constant, cache settings, etc.).

This doesn't work and I can't understand which is the matter.

Note I have already modified the `composer.json` for `FirstPlugin`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "FirstPlugin\\": "src"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "FirstPlugin\\Test\\": "tests",
        "SecondPlugin\\": "vendor/second-plugin-path/src"
    }
},
```

and the `SecondPlugin` is installed via composer and located into `vendor/`.

---

**EDIT**
The exception is thrown here:
http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/source-class-Cake.Core.Plugin.html#149

This means `$config['path']` is empty.

The problem I think is this:
http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/source-class-Cake.Core.Plugin.html#134

Maybe in the bootstrap of test I must set manually the configuration value?

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Even if the problem might be obvious for people that know the CakePHP internals, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead. ps, how can both `FirstPlugin` and `SecondPlugin`,  share the same folder, ie `src`?

Comment: @ndm, sorry, I meant to say that I get a `MissingPluginException` exception running tests. They don't share the same folder, the `SecondPlugin` is installed via composer and it's located into `vendor/`

Comment: rightly, I have set the exact path of the plugin (`vendor /`), but I still have the same problem

Comment: @ndm see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Missing file `vendor/cakephp-plugins.php`.
I noticed that this file is not created for the plugin, but only for the app. Strange.